# How to display image in Umbraco?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

how to display image from my Document Type (Category) info  Templates view?

I tried to insert value but i get this

```
Umbraco.Cms.Core.Models.MediaWithCrops`1[Umbraco.Cms.Web.Common.PublishedModels.Image]
```

Can someone help?

Comment: In order for us to help you, you’ll need to post some code - what does your view look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `MediaWithCrops` type (which it looks like you do) you can use the following:

```
NameOfMediaWithCropsVariable.MediaItem.MediaUrl();
```

Comment: Can you explain this further. I am also trying to display images inside of a loop but I am not sure how to render them.

Answer (score 2):

For developers looking to display images in a loop:

```
@foreach (var item in selection)
{
    var picture = item.Value<IPublishedContent("postImage").GetCropUrl();
    <div class="thumbnail-img" style="background-image:url(@picture)"></div>
}
```